# Stripe Marketplaces Implementation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments

Hi guys I am somewhat new to programming. Does anyone have experience using Stripe Marketplaces? I spent all day trying to wrap my head around it but they are really confusing.

Here is their site: https://stripe.com/us/marketplaces

This is the supposed API call(Where does this go in my code?):

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/transfers \
  -u sk_test_jId8tWpQJuUpj7dtRQnkyH3t: \
  -d amount=400 \
  -d currency=usd \
  -d recipient=rp_103haf2rmKZAYQkmezEC4eza \
  -d bank_account=ba_mBSw34rzSCcT5i0zd34tpPl \
  -d "description=Transfer to test@example.com"
```

I have implemented stripe checkout for Rails: https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/guides/rails

That was very fast and easy but it won't work as I will have to distribute funds after collecting them.(Stripe Connect won't work for what I am doing & I am guessing Stripe Marketplaces is built on top of Stripe Checkout?).

Stripe Marketplaces is rather new and all tutorials out there are for simple stripejs, stripeconnect or stripe checkout but there are none for implementing stripe marketplaces that I could find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Marketplaces" is a use case, not a feature.

You can more easily build a marketplace using [the Stripe API](https://stripe.com/docs/api) to collect payment, take your cut, and transfer the remaining balance to your sellers' bank accounts.

Building the marketplace is up to you. Stripe just makes the billing and accounting easier.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense! How would I go about making the marketplace. Do you know where I can go and learn how to build that? I am guessing I'll be building a charges controller, model & views. And having them belong to a user? Not very very used to using API's unfortunately..

Comment: If you're comfortable with basic Rails and eCommerce, building a marketplace-style store—as you've guessed—basically comes down to users and products having a relationship. So at a high level, you collect the money like you would in any store (using Stripe), but also need to track which user sold the product (so you can transfer their share to them using Stripe). If you're less comfortable with Rails, check out Michael Hartl's tutorial/book or "Agile Web Development with Rails 4." Once you're comfortable with the basics, Stripe's Ruby library is easy to use and well-documented.

Comment: And because Stripe provides a nice Ruby library, it's very familiar; you can do things like `Stripe::Customer.create(description: 'John Smith', email: 'jsmith@example.com')` instead of worrying about the details of JSON APIs.

Comment: Where do I put these things though? In a model? There is no use case of using the Stripe Ruby API on their site.

Comment: That's a matter of personal architectural preference. Model, PORO service class, background worker, controller... Wherever it makes sense to you and your application.